# Old short story featuring a glacier in Oxford Street?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Set during a future ice age. A glacier in Oxford Street. Written in 50s or 60s. It left a strong impression on me as a 13 year old.

Comment: There isn't really a lot to go on here, can you remember anything else about this at all that you could [edit] in?

Comment: No, not really. I thought it was Clarke (the setting after all) but I can't find it in his collections. I'm hoping someone read and remembered it..

Could be Wyndham.

Comment: Thank you for the question! Weirdly that story has also been going through my head quite a bit recently, kept meaning to ask here myself

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably ["The Forgotten Enemy" by Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forgotten_Enemy), borrowable at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/collectedstories00clar/page/154/mode/2up?q=forgotten+enemy). It was first published in 1949 in the *New Worlds* magazine, then appeared in the 1956 collection *Reach for Tomorrow*.

> The Solar System has dived into a belt of cosmic dust; Britain's climate has changed from temperate to arctic.
>
> Professor Millward has stayed with his books, when the country was abandoned more than twenty years ago, and lost track of the others' attempts to colonize the rapidly transforming jungles and deserts of the south, also via the radio, some years later. He is now sheltering from the cold in the edifice of a London university. Over months, he is haunted by a mysterious sound from the north, which he attributes to "mountains on the march", in his dreams. Roaming about the snow-bound familiar roads and houses of the city long after the last stray dogs have disappeared from them, he is surprised by wolves, reindeer, and polar bears, and therefore ponders if the roaring in the north may be caused by an expedition from North America across the frozen-over Atlantic or by efforts to free the land from ice and snow with atomic bombs. When he climbs to his usual look-out, on an especially clear day, he finally detects the real origin of the northern sound, catching sight of the glitter of a threatening mass of glacial ice that is relentlessly advancing towards him.

Found by searching the web for `short story glacier london` (I thought that Oxford Street might be a bit too specific and/or misremembered, maybe it was another street in London).

Comment: Yes, that's it! Odd that I missed it. I'm usually good at Googling. Many thanks Rand.

Comment: It might help to relieve your inner 13-year-old to know that glaciers can't accumulate any faster than it snows. -- Please click on the checkmark to indicate that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Also here: https://archive.org/details/Avon_Science_Fiction_And_Fantasy_Reader_v01n01_1953-01/page/n18/mode/1up